# How to check if column is string

Tags: hive

How to check in hive whether the column is holding string character. My column is string datatype and has values like below

```
my_col string 
000001234
0001111
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to check, whether string character is present is following:

```
SELECT
my_col,
CASE WHEN HEX(LOWER(my_col)) <> HEX(UPPER(my_col)) then 'char present' else 'no char' END char_check
FROM my_table;
```

We convert value to lower case and upper case and cast it to hexadecimal.

`HEX('1a')` produces 3161

`HEX('1A')` produces 3141

And that's how we know that a character is present which can be converted to upper or lower case.

It's a quick workaround, otherwise I would create UDF with Java.